# Mozilla 1.7 - open multiple urls at once from the command line

Tags: mozilla

I am making on a reporting tool which outputs the reports as HTML. Unfortunately, the report sometimes needs to be viewed on machined running only Mozilla 1.7 on Solaris 9. My problem is that I have to support an option to open multiple reports in separate windows (or tabs, if that's the only option).
To launch Mozilla, I create a new process and pass the report url on the command line:
`/path/to/mozilla-bin file:///path/to/report.html`

Is there a way to open more than one URL without creating one process per URL?
If there is no way, how would one open multiple URLs, one per process, but using the same Mozilla profile?

All help is appreciated

**EDIT:** just realized this should probably be posted on SuperUser. Mod, please move it there if possible. Sorry.

Comment: "Mozilla 1.7" - as in "Mozilla Suite anno 2004"? Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, Mozilla has source code archives going all the way back. It seems that the command line handling code of Mozilla 1.7 will [pass the command line argument to the browser window verbatim](http://mxr.mozilla.org/aviarybranch/source/xpfe/bootstrap/nsAppRunner.cpp#635). As to the browser window, it will [split that parameter by the newline (`\n`) character](http://mxr.mozilla.org/aviarybranch/source/xpfe/browser/resources/content/navigator.js#561) to get the list of addresses to load. So I guess that your application needs to pass `"file:///path/to/report.html\nfile:///path/to/report2.html\nfile:///path/to/report3.html"` as parameter, that should work to open multiple tabs.